# Dotfuscator UWP command exited with code 1

Tags: xamarin, uwp, dotfuscator, preemptive

I am configuring my Xamarin solution to obfuscate the code using Dotfuscator using [this](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/getting_started_xamarin.html) instructions, all went fine with my Android and iOS projects, but I'm not being able to get it working with UWP. My UWP project is targeting v10.0.15063 and I've tried with Dotfuscator CE v5.30.0.5167 and v5.32.1.6167 with no luck.

The error:

> El comando ""C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\PreEmptiveSolutions\DotfuscatorCE\dotfuscatorCLI.exe"
>   /p:InDir="obj\x86\Release\DotfuscatorXamarin\dfin",OutDir="obj\x86\Release\DotfuscatorXamarin\dfout",ReportDir="DotfuscatorReports\x86\Release"
>   "DotfuscatorConfig.xml"" salió con el código 1.

Anyone can help?

### Updated

I've changed the log level of VS build to normal and this is what I get:

```
1>  [Resultado de la compilación] Analizando el marcado...  
1>  [Resultado de la compilación] El valor no puede ser nulo.  
1>  Nombre del parámetro: key  
1>  [Resultado de la compilación] Error de compilación.
```

Comment: I develop Dotfuscator, and I have two questions of clarification. **(1)** Dotfuscator CE is installed as a Visual Studio extension, but the path you give doesn't look like that. Is that actually the path where the executable resides? **(2)** The PowerShell error looks to be a generic error, not one generated by Dotfuscator. Rather than trying to reproduce the issue in the shell, try setting Visual Studio's verbosity to *Normal* and building again to see more error details. There's a link for how to do that in the Dotfuscator-Xamarin instructions you referenced.

Comment: I've installed Dotfuscator CE as a Visual Studio Extension, this is v5.30.0.5167, after that I've downloaded v5.32.1.6167 from Dotfuscator site and copied extracted folder to the path shown at the error, changing the DotfuscatorXamarinCliPath config property to try if the newest version resolves the issue. I will change the verbosity of the build log and update here my results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer*: I work for the Dotfuscator team at PreEmptive Solutions, and am answering this question in that capacity.

The issue you mention appears to be one we recently fixed, relating to Dotfuscator being unable to determine the type a `DataContext` is set to.

Currently the fix is available in Professional Edition 4.33.0, [available here](https://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/downloads). There's not presently a version of Community Edition with the fix, but you may be able to work around the issue by disabling markup analysis. To do so, [set a project property](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/ce/docs/help/gui_buildsettings.html#pctoc-project-properties-tab) with the name `disable_markup_analysis` and value `true`.